# django formset initial data showing id (primary key)

Tags: django

For some reason, the exclude in my forms isn't working and the primary key of my Item models is showing up on my formset. How can I get rid of it?

Form:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = Item
          fields = ('name', 
              'description',
              'quantity',      
              'start',
              'end',
              'cost_price',
              'selling_price',)
          widgets = {
               'cost_price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'onChange':'updateSellingPrice()'}),
               'description': forms.Textarea,
               'start': SelectDateWidget,
               'end': SelectDateWidget}
          exclude = ('id')

     ItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(Item, form=ItemForm, max_num=5, extra=3, exclude=('id'))
```

View:

```
def item_details(request, event_slug, role_id, module_slug):
     event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event_slug)
     payment_details = EventPaymentDetail.objects.get_or_create(event=event)[0]

     try:
          item_details = Item.objects.filter(event=event)
     except:
          item_details = Item.objects.get_or_create(event=event)[0]

     if request.method == 'POST':
          item_formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST)

          #display_error(request, item_formset)
          if item_formset.is_valid():
               instances = item_formset.save(commit=False)
               for instance in instances:
                    instance.event = event
                    instance.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Item details successfully saved!')
               url = reverse('event_admin_dashboard', args=[event_slug, role_id])
          return redirect(url)

      else:
           item_formset = ItemFormSet()
           currency_type = payment_details.currency
           template = 'registration/item_details.html'

      return render(request, template, locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to exclude the id field. I'm afraid I can't give you an explanation or a link to the docs.

## Aside:

It's not the issue here, but you're missing a comma on your `exclude` tuple. That's not the problem here, but it means that django interprets it as

```
exclude = ('i', 'd')
```

It should be:

```
exclude = ('id',)
```

Comment: Found the answer! In the template, I can do a check for field.is_hidden to play around with my content blocks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You could rewrite your comment as an answer so that other people can find it more easily.